# When Go source file named arm.go, no identifiers are recognized

Tags: go

I believe this is a bug in the current Golang implementation, but I'm not completely sure.

Say I have two Go source files:

test1.go:

```
package tmp

func test1() {
    test2()
}
```

other.go:

```
package tmp

func test2() {}
```

They build with no errors; test2() is located in package tmp by test1()

However, if I rename other.go to arm.go, the compiler gives:

```
undefined: test2
```

... it's rather strange; any other name seems to work fine, except arm.go. Ideas?

Comment: No, I'm just getting the messages through Syntastic in vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arm.go file name is special (see http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints). The file will only be built on GOARCH=arm. I suspect you have different CPU, so the file is excluded.

Alex

Comment: Hey @alex (Alex B), if you see this do you think you could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69892743/spnego-on-go-backend-windows-server please?

Comment: @AndrewW.Phillips I did look. I cannot help you. I am not sure why you even asked me.