# SPNEGO on Go backend (Windows server)

Tags: go, active-directory, kerberos, spnego

I currently have an application running on our Windows Intranet consisting of a backend (Golang) and multiple frontends.  Currently frontend users must authenticate to the backend using a password but we want to move to SSO (single sign-on) for improved security and user convenience. The frontend can use SPNEGO to negotiate IAW (Integrated Windows Authentication) which would allow the backend to know the Windows login ID of the frontend user.

I know how to configure the frontend (web browsers) for this and it would be handled automatically in the backend if I was using IIS for the web server.  I just need the equivalent code for a Go web server.

https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/v8 appears to support this but I have been unable to get it to work.  There is some example code such as https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/blob/master/examples/example-AD.go but I have not been able to understand how to adapt it to my needs.  Does anyone have a working example?

Comment: Added an issue to github project for what appears to be a bug
https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/issues/451

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Let's see your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @T-Heron. I don't have a configuration file.  I guess that is what I am trying to create. The gokrb5 examples use encoded binary data, but I think that is some sort of standard test data.